# Can the string for "set title" be obtained from a file?

Tags: gnuplot

I'm using Gnuplot with scripts and data files.

In my script there is a command;

set title "blah title here"

Is it possible to have that string taken from a data file?  e.g. such that I can use a single script with many data files, because the data file will contain the title for the plot.

Comment: Thanks for your answers guys; I think the conclusion is you basically can't, and so I'm now taking the approach of using in-line data (e.g. data in the gnuplot script itself).

Comment: having the tool which produces the data also produce the gnuplot script to plot it is a method which I've resorted to from time to time.  Good luck.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if this would be easy to do in pure gnuplot, but here is a solution using a wrapper bash script.  You would use the script by calling `plotscript.sh data.dat` at the command line.

```
#!/bin/bash

my_title=$(head -n 1 $1 | sed 's/^# \(.*\)/\1/')

echo "set terminal postscript enhanced color
set output 'plot.eps'

set title '$my_title'
plot '$1' u 1:2" | gnuplot
```

To make the script usable put the code in a textfile and run `chmod +x` on it.  If you tell me what format the title is in I can try to tailor the script to match that.  This script assumes that the title is the first line of the data file in this type of format:

```
# mytitle

1 4
2 5
3 2
```

Comment: (+1) In some ways, I think this solution is more elegant than mine.  My only suggestion would be to use a here file instead of `echo`.  e.g. `gnuplot <<EOF #commands go here with newlines and everyhing. newline.EOF`.  This has the advantage that you can still use double quotes in the document without escaping them.

Answer (score 2):

you can use backtic substitution...e.g.

```
set title "`head -1 datafile.dat`"
```

However, that doesn't quite get what you want since the backtic substitution is done prior to string operations (You can't specify the datafile name as a string).  However, Macros are expanded prior to backtic substitutions.

My test datafile looked like:

```
"this is the title"
10 20
20 30
30 40
```

And my test script looked like:

```
DATAFILE="datafile.dat"
set macro
TI='`head -1 '.DATAFILE.'`'  #macro: Single quotes are important here to prevent expansion of backtics.
set title @TI
plot DATAFILE u 1:2 title columnhead(1)
```

Note that if your title isn't enclosed in double quotes in the datafile, you'll need to add
them so that the resulting `set title` command is valid.  (You can either add them to the macro, or to the datafile)

Answer (score 1):

Even if this is rather late and the OP's account doesn't exist anymore, I need to add an answer, because it is simply not true that you cannot extract a title from a datafile with gnuplot *only*.

You can run `stats` (check `help stats`) without actually being interested in statistics but just for extracting the title.
You limit the data to the line of interest via `every` (check `help every`).
This works for gnuplot 4.6.0 (March 2012).

For gnuplot>=4.6.0 you can set a character as datafile separator (check `help datafile separator`). Take a character which doesn't appear in the line with the title. For gnuplot>=4.6.0 you can `set datafile separator "\t"` or for gnuplot>=5.0.0 you can also `set datafile separator "\n"`.

**Data:**  `SO10968529.dat`

```
# This is a commented line
"Line2: This is a uncommented line in double quotes"
"Line3: my Title"

Line5: This is a title without quotation marks
"Line6: Another title"
# x   y
  1   5.0
  2   3.0
  3   4.0
  4   2.0
# end of data
```

**Script:**

```
### read title from datafile
reset

FILE = "SO10968529.dat"

set multiplot layout 1,2

    set datafile separator "\t"
    stats FILE u (myTitle=strcol(1),0) every ::0:0:0:0 nooutput
    set datafile separator whitespace
    set title myTitle
    plot FILE u 1:2 w lp pt 7 lc rgb "red"

    set datafile separator "\t"
    stats FILE u (myTitle=strcol(1),0) every ::0:1:0:1 nooutput
    set datafile separator whitespace
    set title myTitle
    plot FILE u 1:2 w lp pt 7 lc rgb "blue"

unset multiplot
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]