# gnuplot: set columnheader as label

Tags: label, gnuplot, columnheader

Is there a chance to set the header of the data file columns as label (not as key)?

I have data files with 5 or 6 columns and a header above each column. Now I would like to use the columnheader with the `set label` command. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a [unixoid system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Unix_commands), the `head` command helps:

```
header = system("head -n 1 ".filename)
label1 = word(header,1)
label2 = word(header,2)
...
set label 1 at 0.5,0.5 label1
set label 2 ....
```

[MS win](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Windows_commands) does not have the `head` command, you might use `'findstr /B \"#\"'` instead, if the header line begins with a "#". Or use [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.org)  to get a full GNU + POSIX environment under Windows.

The `word()` function should split your header string at the same positions as `columnhead()`. Unless of course you have a different separator (not space or tab):

```
separator =","
p1 = strstrt(header,separator)
p2 = strstrt(header[p1+1:],separator)
...
label1=header[1:p1-1]
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Today I had the chance to test it. But I get an error that says `The command "head" is either misspelled or was not found`. So I tried `header = system("< head -n 1".filename)`. This also gives an error: `The system can not find the specified file.`

Comment: With the "<", your system will try to feed a local file "head" into the variable, that can't work. You seem to not have the "head" program from the gnu core utilities. Have you tried running it on the system shell? (You are on a linux system?)

Comment: I have windows and I think the problem is that the `head` command is not available on the windows shell. So I tried to run my script with `wgnuplot` but there I get `popen failed`. So I have no idea what this means.

Comment: No, it's not available. If your header line begins with a "#" (and is the only line that does so), `"findstr /B \"#\" ".filename` would be the ticket.

Comment: So I have multiple lines beginning with "#" this will not work. But I managed to run gnuplot via cygwin and now I can use the `header = system("head -1 ".filename)` command. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Good thinking. ;-) I added that to my answer.

Comment: @Froop here is a platform-independent gnuplot-only solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72306388/7295599 there it is used for the title, but of course can also be used for a label.