# Getting plot title and caption data from the data file

Tags: gnuplot

Consider the following file that I want to plot using gnuplot: `Servos20211222_105253.csv`

```
# Date/Time 2021/12/22, 10:52:53
# PonE=0,LsKp=200,LsKi=0,LsKd=250,HsKp=40,HsKi=0,HsKd=130,Sp=800,TDEC=1175137
#
# Rel. Time, currentPos, PosPID, currentSpeed, speedPID, Lag, ServoPos
0.00000,4693184,0,0,0,0,4693184
0.00000,4693184,2300,0,368,0,4693184
0.00391,4693185,2300,12,367,0,4693184
 :
 :
```

I would like to:

- set the plot title to the date/time from the first comment record.
- display the record that starts "# PonE" as a caption.
- extract the value for TDEC and plot a horizontal line with the name "Target"

I have some influence over the format of the header records, so if (for example) it would be better that they were not comments but provided in some other way, then that can be done.

Answer (score 1):

It is a [common problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968529/can-the-string-for-set-title-be-obtained-from-a-file) to get text values from files using only gnuplot. If you can use OS and shell dependent solutions, I'd suggest to use remove the comments from the file and try something like

```
set title "`head -1 Servos20211222_105253.csv`"
```

You can place text anywhere using `set label <"label text">`, where the label text can be the 2nd line from the file.

You can plot a straight line using plot:

```
p sin(x), 0.5 title "TDEC"
```

But instead of 0.5, you need to get the value using shell scripts again, e.g. the `cut` unix command.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways with gnuplot only, although sometimes a bit cumbersome compared with using tools which you have available on Linux (or comparable tools which you need to install on Windows).

***Update:*** shorter and "simplified" script

One possible *gnuplot-only* way:

- set `commentschar` to nothing, i.e. `''`
- assign the columns to variables and/or arrays, e.g. `myDate`, `myTime`, `P[1..9]`.
- Merge `P[1..8]` into a multi-line string `Params` by "mis"-using `sum` (check `help sum`)
- Convert `P[9]` into a floating point number `TDEC` for plotting

**Script:** (modified the data a bit just for illustration)

```
### extract values from headers with gnuplot only
reset session

$Data <<EOD
# Date/Time 2021/12/22, 10:52:53
# PonE=0,LsKp=200,LsKi=0,LsKd=250,HsKp=40,HsKi=0,HsKd=130,Sp=800,TDEC=1175137
#
# Rel. Time, currentPos, PosPID, currentSpeed, speedPID, Lag, ServoPos
0.00000,1300000,0,0,0,0,4693184
0.00200,1200000,2300,0,368,0,4693184
0.00391,1100000,2300,12,367,0,4693184
EOD

set datafile separator comma commentschar '' 
array P[9]    # array to store parameters
stats $Data u ($0==0 ? (myDate=strcol(1)[3:], myTime=strcol(2)) : \
          sum [_i=1:9] (P[_i] = _i==1 ? strcol(_i)[3:] : strcol(_i) ,0 )) \
          every ::0::1 nooutput
set datafile commentschar      # set back to default

Params = P[1]
Params = (sum [_i=2:8] (Params=Params.sprintf("\n%s",P[_i]),0),Params)

set title sprintf("%s %s", myDate, myTime)
TDEC = real(P[9][6:])       # convert to real number
set label 1 at graph 0.02, first TDEC P[9] offset 0,-0.7
set label 2 at graph 0.02, graph 0.85 Params

plot $Data u 1:2 w lp pt 7 title "Data", \
     TDEC w l lc "red" title "Target"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: My, I'm impressed!   Given the hoops you had to jump through, I think I may be better trying to use Octave to do this using textread and dlmread.  I'll start another thread.

Comment: @DavidPartridge so, maybe even the updated shortened version will not convince you? I've seen that your Octave question hasn't gotten any answer yet. For which solution did you go?

Comment: Octave:

fname = 'ServoY20220421_111021'
file = [fname, '.csv']
## Open file (to be sure just for reading)

fid = fopen (file, "r");

## Get date & msecs from first line
line1 = fgetl(fid);
C = textscan (line1, "# Date/Time %s %s", 1);
dattim = strjoin (cell2mat (C), " ");

## Get TDEC from second line
line2 = fgetl (fid)
line3 = fgetl (fid)
fclose (fid);

Comment: @DavidPartridge Glad to hear that you found a solution. I would recommend that you answer your own (Octave) question. This would help others with the same or similar issue. That's the idea of StackOverflow.