# gnuplot: how to read first line of datafile.txt and set is as title

Tags: gnuplot

have a txt file:

```
Nameofgraph
x y
0 1
3 4
5 7
```

need to plot y(x) with title "Nameofgraph"

maybe something of

```
(read first line as string)
set title title_name
nskip=1 
plot filename skip nskip x:y
```

Comment: Like that? https://stackoverflow.com/a/72306388/7034621

Answer (score 0):

found a way:

```
set title "`head -1 filename.txt`"
```